# actionscript 3 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before y

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem. I try to make a restart function, but I got this massage
Level1, Layer 'action', Frame 24, Line 96   1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before y.
this is the code:

```
function resetGame():void {
ball.y == 200.y
ball.x == 275.x
playerPaddle.y == 200.y
cpuPaddle.y == 200.y
}
```

pleas Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should rather be:

```
function resetGame():void {
    ball.y = 200;
    ball.x = 275;
    playerPaddle.y = 200;
    cpuPaddle.y = 200;
}
```

**Note** : you are using equality operator [`==`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#equality) instead of the assignment operator [`=`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#assignment)